# Values in json array are nil

Tags: json, swift, swift2

Beginner, so please bear with my poor programming language and skills.

I receive this json array of strings from my MySQL through a PHP-script to my iOS Swift 2 app:

```
(
    "{\"id\":\"0\",\"category\":\"ah\",\"createdAt\":\"0000-00-00\",\"expires\":\"ah\",\"location\":\"ah\",\"country\":\"ah\",\"freetext\":\"ah\"}",
    "{\"id\":\"0\",\"category\":\"hej\",\"createdAt\":\"0000-00-00\",\"expires\":\"hej\",\"location\":\"hej\",\"country\":\"hej\",\"freetext\":\"hej\"}",
    "{\"id\":\"0\",\"category\":\"News\",\"createdAt\":\"0000-00-00\",\"expires\":\"Now\",\"location\":\"Here\",\"country\":\"This\",\"freetext\":\"Ah!\"}"
)
```

I want to append each value ("id", "category" etc.) to my own arrays which will populate my tableview. You see my approach below.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DemandTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var demandIdArray: [String] = [String]()
    var demandCategoryArray: [String] = [String]()
    var demandCreatedAtArray: [String] = [String]()
    var demandExpiresArray: [String] = [String]()
    var demandLocationArray: [String] = [String]()
    var demandCountryArray: [String] = [String]()
    var demandFreetextArray: [String] = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var demandTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.demandTableView.delegate = self
        self.demandTableView.dataSource = self

        //retrieve new demand data
        self.getDemandData()
    }

    func getDemandData() {
        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://picondemand.com/demands/demand_data.json")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("Connection OK!")

                do
                {
                    //cast data as array
                    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://picondemand.com/demands/demand_data.json")!)
                    if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
                    {

                    print("Number of demands: \(jsonArray.count)")

                        print(jsonArray)

                        for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.count ; i++ )
                        {
                            let demands = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i)
                            print("\(demands)")

                            /*
                            // GET VALUES FOR "id", "category" etc

                            let id:String? = demands["id"] as? String
                            self.demandIdArray.append(id!)

                            */
                        }

                    }

                } catch {
                    print("\(error)")
                }

                self.demandTableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        ///////create a table cell
        let DemandCell: DemandTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DemandCell") as! DemandTableViewCell

        /////// customize the cell
        DemandCell.idLabel.text = ("Id: \(demandIdArray[indexPath.row])")
        DemandCell.categoryLabel.text = ("Category: \(demandCategoryArray[indexPath.row])")
        DemandCell.createdAtLabel.text = ("Created at: \(demandCreatedAtArray[indexPath.row])")
        DemandCell.expiresLabel.text = ("Expires: \(demandExpiresArray[indexPath.row])")
        DemandCell.locationLabel.text = ("Location: \(demandLocationArray[indexPath.row])")
        DemandCell.countryLabel.text = ("Country: \(demandCountryArray[indexPath.row])")
        DemandCell.freetextLabel.text = ("Description: \(demandFreetextArray[indexPath.row])")

        /////// return the cell
         return DemandCell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return demandIdArray.count
    }
}
```

**My problem is I can't get the values; they are nil. What is wrong?**

There are many questions regarding this topic on SO, however, none has done it for me. I've tried so many random approaches now I'm starting to feel dizzy.

- using valueForKey[] on jsonArray level doesn't work. (*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x1759bbc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.')

What's a NSCFString!?

- my demands is of type AnyObject. To me this should be the inner level of my data. I have no idea how to proceed with this one, or even if this is the right approach at all. I found the loop solution here on SO but it only took med this far. Print("(id)") gives me nil.

I have tried swiftyJSON as well.

Comment: at first, your data are NOT valid JSON. what you got as jsonArray is an array of strings. all of them seems to be valid JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parsing can not work correctly because your JSON format is not that what you want. Look at your JSON via http://www.jsoneditoronline.org and you will see on the right hand side that your JSON represents an array of 3 strings and not an array of 3 dictionaries.

If you adapt your JSON like the one below it represents an array or 3 dictionaries and you can parse ID and whatnot out of it :-)

```
[
  {
    "id":"0",
    "category":"ah",
    "createdAt":"0000-00-00",
    "expires":"ah",
    "location":"ah",
    "country":"ah",
    "freetext":"ah"
    },

  {"id":"0",
  "category":"hej",
  "createdAt":"0000-00-00",
  "expires":"hej",
  "location":"hej",
  "country":"hej",
  "freetext":"hej"
  },

  {"id":"0",
  "category":"News",
  "createdAt":"0000-00-00",
  "expires":"Now",
  "location":"Here",
  "country":"This",
  "freetext":"Ah!"
  }
]
```

Put this in the JSONEditor and you will see the correct representation. Also you do not need \" in JSON.

Comment: he has an array of strings. every string in his array represents valid JSON object. the escape \ are necessary there.

Comment: Ah, I started to assume the problem originated on server side! I'll look into this tonight and Rhen check your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user3441734 but he does not want an array of strings. when you look at his code he wants to have an array of dictionaries where he then wants to access his properties by "demands["id"]" and therefore he needs to adapt his json only.

Comment: he wrote "I receive this json array of strings ..." please, see my note below his question

Comment: @user3441734, what do you suggest?

Comment: @DanAbnormal are you the author of the server side PHP script?

Comment: Yes @user3441734 I am

Comment: in that case, you have to decide. i suggest you to produce valid JSON on server side.

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler, I have accepted your answer :-) don't want to think about all the hours spent doing the right thing wrong.